# Error on boot: no such partition grub rescue

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, grubrescue

I have a dual boot system (Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.04.02), However recently I have changed my motherboard and since then I am getting an error. I have reinstalled both of my operating systems and followed these but it was still no use:

- [How To Solve: error: no such partition grub rescue in Ubuntu Linux](http://itsfoss.com/solve-error-partition-grub-rescue-ubuntu-linux/)
- [Recovering from 'grub rescue>' crash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/148041/recovering-from-grub-rescue-crash)

I have tried installing `lilo` by using a live-disc which gave me access to Windows, but if I reinstall Ubuntu I get the same error at startup again. I want to get back to the grub2 boot menu so that I can access both Windows and Ubuntu.
this is how it looks: http://i.ytimg.com/vi/zwed_1NqAZI/maxresdefault.jpg
 (sorry couldn't upload an image)
and here is the link after performing boot repair: paste.ubuntu.com/10739355/

Comment: This may be helpful: https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/776643-how-to-rescue-a-non-booting-grub-2-on-linux/ - read the "booting from grub-rescue>" section in particular (I would read all of it).

Comment: Also see http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/168689/100763

Comment: error : unknown file system in 3out of 4 and error: failure reading sector 0x2 from 'fd0'

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Comment: no @David Foerster ..I installed Ubuntu after windows ..its not that issue

Comment: The answers to that question don't just apply to the part of the question title between parentheses. Did you try to run Boot-Repair as recommended per one of the answers? If so, I'd like to see the log file to maybe find some more hints to the cause of the issue.

Comment: You don't explicitly say what error message you're seeing. Reporting the *exact* error message is important to even begin debugging problems. If necessary, take a photo with a digital camera and post it as part of your question.

Comment: I have updated the log file and screenshot check it if needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would if I were you, based on the information your provided:

- Boot from a live CD
- [Back-up my data](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc)
- Format the hard drive
- Reinstall Windows in BIOS mode
- Reinstall Ubuntu in BIOS mode
- Restore my data

Comment: thanks for the solution ,it worked.. but any idea what could have been the reason for this problem?

Comment: When you change the motherboard of the computer you change a lot of things at the same time...  So it's just easier to reinstall and change all modules then to try and find the single module in your old set-up that was causing the problem...

Answer (score 0):

Does your HDD have a recovery partition before the ESP?

On some UEFI systems, it requires a recovery partition at the beginning of the drive and the ESP as the second partition.
 and of course gpt partition tables for UEFI.